# Error in pickle file in _io.BufferedWriter

Tags: python, pickle, readfile

I am trying to extract the contents of pickle file but getting '_io.BufferedWriter' errorbelow i have attached the code. Thanks in advance

```py
pickle_out = open("/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/new_dataset/labels.pickle","wb")                    
pickle.dump(label_names, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-bf2ff17c7703> in <cell line: 4>()
      2 
      3 pickle_out = open("/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/new_dataset/labels.pickle","wb")
----> 4 pickle.dump(label_names, pickle_out)
      5 pickle_out.close()
      6 

TypeError: cannot pickle '_io.BufferedWriter' object
```

Comment: What is *label_names* ?

Comment: You are not trying to extract the contents of a pickle file (i.e. read its contents). You are trying to write a pickle file instead. As per the other commenter, we can't help you any further if you don't give us any more information about `label_names`.